# System.InvalidCastException: The conversion is not valid

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, linq

I get the correct numbers out of the variable(in this case 11) but I cannot compare it because I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: The conversion is not valid

both values are int. I cannot seem to find the problem.

```
Dim id = CInt(Request.QueryString("id"))
Dim uk = From hj In dc.Orders _
         Where hj.UserID = id _
         Select hj
```

Comment: as i said. Integer. Ill try to restart vs and the webserver, always helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that by just having `Dim id` that it's getting created as an object, not an integer.  Try:

```
Dim id as Integer
id = CInt(Request.QueryString("id"))
```

Actually, you should probably be using

Integer.TryParse(Request.QueryString("id"),id)

just in case someone passes in a non-int param.

Comment: Lol, simple misstake by me. thank god its friday! :) will mark as answer in 4 mins